# gathering value from date condition in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I something like below mentioned dataframe (for the example):

```
ACC_ID       ACC_TYPE        Date          Value
DII-11       RD              05-01-2018    25
DII-11       RD              10-01-2018    35
DII-11       RD              13-01-2018    20
DII-11       RD              14-01-2018    28
DII-11       RD              17-01-2018    29
DII-11       RD              01-02-2018    14
DII-11       JS              05-02-2018    25
DII-11       JS              10-02-2018    35
DII-11       JS              13-02-2018    20
DII-11       JS              14-02-2018    28
DII-11       JS              17-02-2018    29
DII-11       JS              20-02-2018    14
DII-11       JS              18-03-2018    10
DII-12       JD              20-03-2018    25
DII-12       JD              05-04-2018    25
DII-12       JD              11-04-2018    25
DII-12       JD              20-04-2018    25
DII-12       JD              04-05-2018    25
DII-12       JD              10-05-2018    25
DII-12       JD              15-05-2018    25
DII-12       JD              19-05-2018    25
DII-12       JD              19-06-2018    25
```

From utilizing the above dataframe, I need to gather an Value from date 5,10,15, 20 and 25 of past three month from the most extreme month aggregate by `ACC_ID` and `ACC_TYPE`. On the off chance that for any month in the event that we don't have push for 05,10,15,20 and 25 than give the estimation of past date (i.e if 20 isn't accessible than give estimation of 19 if 19 isn't than 18 and so on).

In the event that any month isn't accessible than demonstrate the Null incentive there.

In the below mentioned sample output, I have kept `Date_1` to `Date_4` and `Value_1` to Value_4`for the sake of simplicity, for the real output the range would be`Date_1`to`Date_15`and value range be`Value_1`to`Value_15`.

Required Output:

```
ACC_ID     ACC_TYPE      Max_Month   Date_1     Value_1  Date_2     Value_2    Date_3     Value_3        Date_4       Value_4
DII-11     RD            Feb-18      05-01-2018 25       10-01-2018 35         14-01-2018 28             17-01-2018   29
DII-11     JS            Mar-18      05-02-2018 25       10-02-2018 35         14-02-2018 28             17-02-2018   29
DII-12     JD            Jun-18      04-05-2018 25       10-05-2018 25         15-05-2018 25             19-05-2018   25
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting but very specific process. What code have you tried? Is there a reason you chose `13-01-2018` over `14-01-2018`? Do you always go to the closest *preceding* date when one is missing? (As opposed to *nearest*.) This seems like a good combination of `dplyr::group_by`, `seq.Date`, and perhaps `findInterval`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks...It was my bad. Yes, I'm trying `group_by` to get the required output but stuck from 5 hours and no progress yet..:(

Comment: @r2evans How to use `findInterval` here, because it will change for every `ACC_ID`.

Comment: ergo `group_by(ACC_ID, ACC_TYPE)`

Comment: @r2evans Please suggest me the approach to get the required output.

Comment: If you have many columns, would it be difficult to view and interpret in the wide format instead of the long

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, get the `max` formatted 'year-month' Date grouped by 'ACC_ID', and 'ACC_TYPE', subset the first four `lead` observations for 'Date' and 'Value' per group and `dcast` to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[,  max_month := max(as.yearmon(dmy(Date))) , .(ACC_ID, ACC_TYPE)]
df1[, c('DateP', 'ValueP') := shift(.SD, type = 'lead'),
              .(ACC_ID, ACC_TYPE), .SDcols = c('Date', 'Value')]
dcast(df1[!is.na(DateP)][, head(.SD, 4), .(ACC_ID, ACC_TYPE)],
   ACC_ID + ACC_TYPE + max_month ~ rowid(ACC_ID, ACC_TYPE), 
             value.var = c('DateP', 'ValueP'), sep = ".")
#  ACC_ID ACC_TYPE max_month    DateP.1    DateP.2    DateP.3    DateP.4
#1: DII-11       JS  Mar 2018 10-02-2018 13-02-2018 14-02-2018 17-02-2018
#2: DII-11       RD  Feb 2018 10-01-2018 13-01-2018 14-01-2018 17-01-2018
#3: DII-12       JD  Jun 2018 05-04-2018 11-04-2018 20-04-2018 04-05-2018
#   ValueP.1 ValueP.2 ValueP.3 ValueP.4
#1:       35       20       28       29
#2:       35       20       28       29
#3:       25       25       25       25
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ACC_ID = c("DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", 
"DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-11", 
"DII-11", "DII-11", "DII-12", "DII-12", "DII-12", "DII-12", "DII-12", 
"DII-12", "DII-12", "DII-12", "DII-12"), ACC_TYPE = c("RD", "RD", 
"RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "JS", "JS", "JS", "JS", "JS", "JS", "JS", 
"JD", "JD", "JD", "JD", "JD", "JD", "JD", "JD", "JD"), Date = c("05-01-2018", 
"10-01-2018", "13-01-2018", "14-01-2018", "17-01-2018", "01-02-2018", 
"05-02-2018", "10-02-2018", "13-02-2018", "14-02-2018", "17-02-2018", 
"20-02-2018", "18-03-2018", "20-03-2018", "05-04-2018", "11-04-2018", 
"20-04-2018", "04-05-2018", "10-05-2018", "15-05-2018", "19-05-2018", 
"19-06-2018"), Value = c(25L, 35L, 20L, 28L, 29L, 14L, 25L, 35L, 
20L, 28L, 29L, 14L, 10L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L)), .Names = c("ACC_ID", "ACC_TYPE", "Date", "Value"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Comment: I want the values of last three months (excluding latest month). For example if for an unique `ACC_ID` my max month is May-18 than i want `Value` of 05th,10th,15th,20th and 25th day of previous month Apr-18, Mar-18 and Feb-18 respectively and for any date if i don;t have any row than value of previous date like if 15th Mar-18 is missing than value of 14th Mar-18, if 14th is missing than 13th Mar-18 and so on.

Comment: I was following the answer from the other post.

Comment: I apologize if my example had confused you, for the sake of simplicity i have written example for only 4 columns, but actually with original dataframe one can get 15 columns for value and 15 for Date. (Five for each Month).

Comment: Please let me know if you have any doubt now.

Comment: How would I get all 15 columns for date and value (5 for every month).

Comment: Where to change in code if I want it on difference of days at 7th, 14th, 21st and 28th.??

Comment: @VectorJX  This is based on the example you provided

Comment: Agreed, but how would I tweak the code to get the desired output.

Comment: When you say 7th 14th, 21st, etc. for a particular month, it is not clear whether all the dates are there for that month.  suppose if the month starts on day 5 and ends on day 20 with only two values 5/10/2017 and 20/10/2017,

Comment: In that case we'll show the value of 20th day of that month in both 21st and 28th.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174543/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

```
dat%>% group_by(ACC_ID,ACC_TYPE)%>%
  mutate(max_month=format(max(dmy(Date)),"%b-%d"),time=1:n())%>%
  slice(1:4)%>%data.frame%>%
 reshape(idvar="ACC_TYPE",dir="wide",v.names = c("Date","Value"))

  ACC_ID ACC_TYPE max_month     Date.1 Value.1     Date.2 Value.2     Date.3 Value.3     Date.4 Value.4
1 DII-11       JS    Mar-18 05-02-2018      25 10-02-2018      35 13-02-2018      20 14-02-2018      28
5 DII-11       RD    Feb-01 05-01-2018      25 10-01-2018      35 13-01-2018      20 14-01-2018      28
9 DII-12       JD    Jun-19 20-03-2018      25 05-04-2018      25 11-04-2018      25 20-04-2018      25


library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, c("max_month","ii") :=. (format(max(dmy(Date)),"%b-%d"), 1:.N ),
                    by=.(ACC_ID,ACC_TYPE)][
   ii %in% 1:4, dcast(.SD, ACC_ID + ACC_TYPE + max_month ~ ii,value.var = c("Date","Value"))]

   ACC_ID ACC_TYPE max_month     Date_1     Date_2     Date_3     Date_4 Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 Value_4
1: DII-11       JS    Mar-18 05-02-2018 10-02-2018 13-02-2018 14-02-2018      25      35      20      28
2: DII-11       RD    Feb-01 05-01-2018 10-01-2018 13-01-2018 14-01-2018      25      35      20      28
3: DII-12       JD    Jun-19 20-03-2018 05-04-2018 11-04-2018 20-04-2018      25      25      25      25
```

Comment: This is not the required output,I want the values of last three months (excluding latest month). For example if for an unique ACC_ID my max month is May-18 than i want Value of 05th,10th,15th,20th and 25th day of previous month Apr-18, Mar-18 and Feb-18 respectively and for any date if i don;t have any row than value of previous date like if 15th Mar-18 is missing than value of 14th Mar-18, if 14th is missing than 13th Mar-18 and so on.

Comment: @VectorJX can you use an example from the table you gave? Eg, for the first group, the maximum month day is Feb-01, so what values do you want and how do you pick them?

Comment: You are right, If the max month is Feb-18 than I want to pick values of 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th and 25th Day of exact last three month (i.e Jan-18,Dec-17 and Nov-17) since for the particular `ACC_ID` we don't have record of Dec-17 and Nov-17 than 10 rows will create with `NA` value.

Comment: I want 15 column of Date and 15 of Value where for any case if the any date out of (05,10,15,20 and 25) are missing than the value should be picked from the previous date (i.e if 20 is missing than 19, if 19 is missing than 18 and so on).